# What SQL queries will help analyse a membership base?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

At our sports centre, I would like to analyse the number and types of subscriptions our members have, but I'm having trouble with the exact SQL queries.

A "subscription" is an entry pass that lets you into specific activities in our sports centre. They have a start and end date, representing the period they are valid. They have an associated activity (eg. "gym", "swim", "group fitness", "rock climbing", etc.)

A member can have more than one subscription. Typically, one will expire before they purchase their next one, but they can have two (or more) valid (or current) subscriptions.

Simplifying a little, we have the following two tables:

```
  Members - stores a member's data, has these columns
    ID (int) - unique ID for a member
    Name (varchar) - the member's name
    Gender (varchar) - the member's gender
    NumGym (int) - number of valid gym passes a member has (derived)
```

and

```
  Subscriptions - holds all the subscriptions we've sold, has these columns
    TypeID (varchar) - unique ID for a subscription type (specifies activity)
    MemberID (int) - the ID of the member that purchased this subscription
    StartDate (datetime) - when the subscription is valid from
    EndDate (datetime) - when the subscription is valid to
```

Some of the questions I would like to be able to ask are:

1. how many members currently have a valid "gym" pass?
2. how many active members do I have on a given day

For (1), I've tried the following:

```
declare @aDay datetime
set @aDay = convert(datetime, '2009-12-08', 102)

update Members m
set NumGym = (select count(memberid)
    from Subscriptions s
    where s.MemberId = m.Id
    and s.TypeID = "Gym"
    and @aDay between s.StartDate and s.EndDate)
```

However it doesn't seem to be producing the correct results (based on our understanding of our membership and some manual counting).

Not having been able to get (1) to work, I haven't tried (2) yet.

Any suggestions on queries to produce what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How many members currently have a valid "gym" pass**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Subscriptions
    WHERE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
          AND TypeID = 'Gym'
```

You should truncate `GETDATE()` here because you want to include `EndDate` as I understood.

"How many members?" is not the same as "How many passes?".

**So "How many members?":**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID)
    FROM Subscriptions
    WHERE @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

**And "How many passes?":**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Subscriptions
    WHERE @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. How many members currently have a valid "gym" pass?

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS s
 WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN s.startdate AND s.enddate
   AND s.typeid = 'Gym'
```

[GETDATE() is a SQL Server function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) you can call to get the current date (and time), rather than construct a date.

### 2. How many active members to I have on a given day (ie. how many valid passes)

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS s
 WHERE @arbitrary_date BETWEEN s.startdate AND s.enddate
```